# Can spray.io can return 504 if Actor accepting Timedout message?

Tags: scala, spray-can

My server is written using spray-can. Let's say inside the receive function I handle Timeout message like this:

```
case Timedout( HttpRequest(m,u,_,_,_)) =>
  sender ! HttpResponse( status = 500, entity = s"can't process $u request timedout" )
```

Is it possible that spray-can itself might response with 504 error ?

Comment: Where is this time out being set? Is this based on your business logic? Or is this a configuration timeout you pass to Spray?

Comment: this is in the logic, like in this example:
https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/examples/spray-can/simple-http-server/src/main/scala/spray/examples/DemoService.scala